# Inverse Operator with a Matrix of operators as entries

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ a Hilbert space, and let $A:H\times H\rightarrow H\times H$ an operator given by

$$A \begin{pmatrix}h_1 \\ h_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}P & Q \\ R &S  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}h_1 \\ h_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Where $P,Q,R,S:H\rightarrow H$ are operators such that $PS-QR$ is invertible.

My question is, could we compute the inverse of the operator $A$ by a similar way when we have complex entries instead of operators? This would be, is this

$$A^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}h_1 \\ h_2 \end{pmatrix}=(PS-QR)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}P & Q \\ R &S  \end{pmatrix}^{*}\begin{pmatrix}h_1 \\ h_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

correct or have we a similar formula? Here, $*$ denotes the adjoint operator.

Thanks

Comment: No.  There is no reason why $A$ is invertible.  For example, $S$ is the unilateral (right) shift on $H=\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ and $P=S^*$ its adjoint, $Q=R=0$.  Then $A$ is not invertible: $A(e_1,0)=(0,0)$, but $PS-QR$ is the identity.

Comment: In general, even if such generalizations hold, you have to be careful to figure out the correct order of the factors because operator multiplication is not commutative. In this specific case, you may want to read up on the Schur complement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).